# MySQL populating all valid_to and modified_by columns knowing all valid_from and created_by values

Tags: mysql, sql

Here is an example of the table I am dealing with:

```
+----+-----------+-------+------------+---------------------+-------------+----------+
| id | object_id | value | created_by |     valid_from      | modified_by | valid_to |
+----+-----------+-------+------------+---------------------+-------------+----------+
|  1 |       333 | a     | Paul       | 2016-06-10 08:15:57 |             |          |
|  3 |       333 | b     | Naomi      | 2016-06-10 09:39:37 |             |          |
|  8 |       333 | c     | Anne       | 2016-06-10 09:46:09 |             |          |
+----+-----------+-------+------------+---------------------+-------------+----------+
```

What is a (preferably) single update statement that would update the table above to the table below?

```
+----+-----------+-------+------------+---------------------+-------------+---------------------+
| id | object_id | value | created_by |     valid_from      | modified_by |      valid_to       |
+----+-----------+-------+------------+---------------------+-------------+---------------------+
|  1 |       333 | a     | Paul       | 2016-06-10 08:15:57 | Naomi       | 2016-06-10 09:39:37 |
|  3 |       333 | b     | Naomi      | 2016-06-10 09:39:37 | Anne        | 2016-06-10 09:46:09 |
|  8 |       333 | c     | Anne       | 2016-06-10 09:46:09 |             |                     |
+----+-----------+-------+------------+---------------------+-------------+---------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using a `join`.  For the data that you have:

```
update t join
       t t2
       on t2.id = t.id + 1
    set t.modified_by = t2.created_by,
        t.valid_to = t2.valid_from;
```

This assumes that the `id`s are sequential as in your example data.

EDIT:

If the values are sequential, you can use a subquery to get the previous one, and then use that for the `join`:

```
update t join
       (select t2.*,
               (select max(t3.id) from t t3 where t3.id < t2.id) as prev_id
        from t t2
       ) t2 
       on t2.prev_id = t.id
    set t.modified_by = t2.created_by,
        t.valid_to = t2.valid_from;
```

Comment: Thank you Gordon. How would this answer change if the ids were still increasing in numbers but not sequential?

Comment: @Dennis You could select the minimum id higher than the current one in each case.

Comment: Found an error. Gordon, could you please change *and* to *,* (comma) in the *SET* clause? Then it would be correct for MySQL.

Comment: How can t2.prev_id = t.id?  That doesn't seem right.

Comment: @chubbsondubs . . . I'm not quite sure how to respond.  It is right.  You want to update the row that has `prev_id` as the `id` value.

Comment: @GordonLinoff But if I have a ROW of ID = 2 and Previous Row ID = 1, then I can't join Row ID = 2 to Previous Row ID =1.  I might be able to join them on some other column, but a previous ID can't be equal to my ID is all I'm saying.  I read Dennis' comment I tried to see why this wouldn't work and I suspect it was that.